# Pycharm (a Python IDE) can only show the first 300 members of a list

Tags: python, pycharm

When I populate a list with more than 300 elements the working environment I'm using to read Python which is Pycharm will only show the first 300 elements.  This applies to both the community editions and the professional edition.  Does anyone know how to fix this and if not does anyone know of an IDE which can display all the elements of a list, even if that list has 10,000 elements?

Again I want to emphasize that for debugging purposes I need to be able to view the elements of a list.

[This shows that more than 300 elements cannot be viewed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/auK4Z.png)

[This shows the length of the list in question.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4bKNy.png)

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just run the script in a terminal?

Comment: I'm not able to replicate this behavior. If I create a list of 10000 integers and then print the list, I get all 10,000 values printed. Please share some code showing how you populate your list and how you show it in the console.

Comment: Printing is not the same as viewing the list while debugging.  When you're debugging and you want to make sure everything is working you have to view the list in the IDE.  You can't view more than 300 elements in a list with the Pycharm IDE.

Comment: @Alex - running the script in the terminal would be too cumbersome and would take up too much time since it would not allow me to locate the cause of bugs quickly.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot or example?

Comment: Screen shots posted.

Comment: @kylefoley76 - Interesting that you describe running the script in the terminal as 'cumbersome'. It seems like that would be a very lightweight method and combined with some clever print statements, achieve all the same debugging functionality as Pycharm.

Comment: On a second thought, I've never really used the Terminal.

Answer (score 28):

Yes, it's possible to show more items with pycharm.

Look at file `helpers/pydev/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_resolver.py`

Edit the `MAX_ITEMS_TO_HANDLE` to whatever you need.

```
# Note: 300 is already a lot to see in the outline (after that the user should really use the shell to get things)
# and this also means we'll pass less information to the client side (which makes debugging faster).
MAX_ITEMS_TO_HANDLE = 500
```

You don't need to restart IDE after the change, just rerun the script.

For Windows 10, the file can be found at `Program Files/JetBrains/PyCharm <version>/helpers/pydev/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_resolver.py`

Comment: The file on MacOS is located at: /Applications/PyCharm\ CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_resolver.py

Answer (score 14):

When I need to inspect long list in debugger I print out the variable with "Evaluate expression" (or alt + F8).

[image: Evaluate expression location]

You will get into the command window.

[image: Evaluate expression command window]

And then you find your variable in the console window.

[image: Console]

Comment: @RodriKing Not only you can inspect large lists but what I found even more useful is that you can run whole block of code when program is paused by debugger thus test prototype code more effectively.

Answer (score 4):

you can add one or more watches for the remainder of the list, having a list such as:

```
my_huge_list = '0' * 1000
```

then add a watch for `my_huge_list[300:]` and then `my_huge_list[600:]` and so on.

It's not super pretty or convenient, but it does work. I'm pretty sure that this can be somehow scripted into pycharm, but my current list has no more than 450 items so this won't be worth it this time.

Answer (score 1):

The question is a few years old but it deals with a problem that remains relevant when using the default settings today. For PyCharm 2019.3 Community Edition on macOS (tested on 10.11.6), the solution is slightly different than in @VaclavKasal's answer. The  settings file is at `/Applications/PyCharm\ CE.app/Contents/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pydev/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_resolver.py`
To display 3000 items, for example, rather than the default 100

change from:

```
# Note: 300 is already a lot to see in the outline (after that the user should really use the shell to get things)
# and this also means we'll pass less information to the client side (which makes debugging faster).
MAX_ITEMS_TO_HANDLE = 300 if not IS_PYCHARM else 100
```

to:

```
# Note: 300 is already a lot to see in the outline (after that the user should really use the shell to get things)
# and this also means we'll pass less information to the client side (which makes debugging faster).
MAX_ITEMS_TO_HANDLE = 300 if not IS_PYCHARM else 3000
```