# Is it possible to increase the number of dictionary items that Eclipse PyDev displays in the Variables view

Tags: python, eclipse, dictionary, pydev

When debugging I want to be able to see all dictionary items in the Variables view.

I get the following message if I try to inspect a dictionary that is greater than 300 items long.

> Unable to handle: Too large to show contents.  Max items to show: 300

[image]

I have just upgraded my instances of Eclipse to the following versions:

- Eclipse (4.6.0)
- PyDev (5.1.2).

With my previous set up I seem to remember that I could inspect very large dictionaries in the Variables view but that lists were truncated to the first 500 items or something.  With very large dictionaries it would take Eclipse a little while to display all of the items.

Makes me wonder whether there has either been a change in Eclipse or PyDev such that it is no longer possible to view all items in such large dictionaries, or whether there is an option in Eclipse or PyDev to adjust the maximum number of dictionary items that the Variables view will display.

I no longer have access to my previous set up so do not know what versions of Eclipse and PyDev I was running (they were a couple of years out of date!!).

I have done the normal Googling and searching of Stack Overflow but I am drawing a blank.  Any help appreciated.

Comment: Same behavior in the latest version of LiClipse (4.6).

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35067932/pycharm-a-python-ide-can-only-show-the-first-300-members-of-a-list